# Printing Array of objects more concisely

Tags: java, arrays, object, printing

I'm creating an array of objects and having an issue in printing this easily

```
Dog Dogobj[]=new Dog[2]; // Dog objects within this array
Dogobj[0] = new Dog(Age, weight, name); 
Dogobj[1] = new Dog(Age, weight, name);

System.out.println("Dog age?: "+Dogobj[0].Dogtype etc.)
```

Now after creating these I can't find an easy way of printing these that isn't a lot of long lines. This is the only way I have found I can do it (above)- there are about 10 variables for each object so they are very long lines.

Comment: Have you added a `toString()` method to your `Dog` class?

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like:

```
for (Dog dog : Dogobj) {
    System.out.println(dog); // This way every dog will be printed in a new line
}
```

And of course, implement Dog's toString method.

in "Dog" class definition:

```
@Overrride
public String toString() {
    "Age: " + age + "," +
    "weight: " + weight + ","
    "name: " + name;
}
```

if you want every dog's member will be printed in a new line, you may implement toString that way:

```
@Overrride
public String toString() {
    "Age: " + age + ",\n" +
    "weight: " + weight + ",\n"
    "name: " + name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement `toString`() method in your DogObj class. Inside this method you can return a string that needs to be printed from the object.
2. Print the objects inside a for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Dogobj.length; i++) {
               System.out.println(DogObj[i]);
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  `for(String d : dog)`
```

1. List item:

   `{System.out.println(d);}`
2. Or this:

`for(int i=0 ; i<dog.length ; i++){ System.out.println(dog[i]);}`